# What is the ec2 cli command to modify the minimum number of nodes in a scaling group?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-cli

I've got an [ec2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) [autoscaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoscaling#Amazon_Web_Services_.28AWS.29) group that starts in the morning and finishes in the evening. I'd like to create a 'button' that people can click to warm up the autoscaling group to run jobs in the middle of the night (only on an on-demand basis).

My question is: **What is the ec2 [cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command to modify the minimum number of nodes in a scaling group?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with `aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity` following the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-manual-scaling.html#as-manual-scaling-aws-cli)

But if you're up to make a button you should look into the various [AWS sdk (on top right is the list of them)](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/) to call the [related API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_SetDesiredCapacity.html) instead of forking to a system command.